# Java synchronized keyword issue

Tags: java, synchronized

I am trying to understand the keyword `synchronized` from the following example

Java `Main` Method -->

```
public int methodA(){

  Hello h = new Hello();
  h.callSomeSynchronizedMethod();    

  sysout("Main");
  return 0;    

}
```

In the `Hello` Class-->

```
public synchronized void callSomeSynchronizedMethod(){
   Hi h = new Hi();

   h.someMethod();

   sysout("Hello");

}
```

In the `Hi` class

```
public void someMethod(){

    sysout("Hi");
}
```

So what would be the list of outputs that i will get;

1.) Is it in the order of `Hi, Hello and Main` ?

2.) What i understand about the synchronized keyword is that it will only execute 1 method and then execute the other, without multi-threading. Is this correct ?

Comment: I think your code is off a bit... there is no "Hello". Cut and paste error maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by no "Hello" ?

Comment: Since your code only ever runs in a single thread, synchronization will have no visible effect whatsoever.

Comment: @sharonHwk It looks like alexblum fixed it. Both of your classes had "Hi" as the print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really understand what synchronized does you need to run the program twice, once synchronized and once not. Also your program should use multiple threads. So here is an example of such a test.

```
public class Synchro {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Synchro();
    }

    public Synchro(){
        final Moo moo = new Moo();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
               moo.aMethod("Second");
           }
        });
        t.start();//calling the method in a thread

        moo.aMethod("First");//calling the same method from the same object in the main thread
     }

 class Moo{     
    public Moo(){            
    }

    public void aMethod(String name){
        //this loop just prints slowly so you can see the execution
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
            System.out.println(String.format("%s : %d", name, i));
            try{
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Now, if you run the above code, noticing that the method is not synchronized, you will see the printout from the two executions of the method interleaved. That is you will see First 1 then Second 1 then First 2 etc.

Now, add the synchronized keyword to the method making it:

```
  public synchronized void aMethod(String name){ ....
```

and run the code again. This time, one execution of the method completes before the other begins.

The synchronized keyword is only necessary when multiple threads are accessing the very same object.

Answer (score 1):

You would get "Hi", then "Hello", then "Main", yes. The synchronized modifier has nothing to do with the order the methods are called in; and, other than adding a bit of overhead, it does nothing at all when running the code in a single thread. You could run this same test without synchronized and get the same result.

Now, if you ran a similar test where multiple threads were calling these methods, your results would be less determinate.

Synchronized is meant to allow for the more safe execution of code and management of resources in a multi-threaded environment.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if its a multi-threaded enviroment synchronize will force to execute 1 method before executing the other ? (Like a procedural program)

Comment: Not quite. A synchronized method can only be executed by a single thread at any time. Other threads trying to execute that method will wait until the lock holder is done.

Answer (score 0):

all these methods will be executed in one thread so the answer for the first question is "yes".

`synchronized` keyword emans that the method can be executed in only one thread at every moment of time. So if you call it from another thread - it will wait till the execution is finished in the first thread.

Answer (score 0):

In Java there is no automatic multithreading: you must explicitly start a thread and pass it a `run` method that it will execute. Only in that case will the `synchronized` keyword start to matter, but its meaning is not quite as you understand it: the methods will execute in whatever thread calls them, but while one is executing, another thread will **block** before it is able to execute a method guarded by the same lock.